# How to run a shell command through vimscript?

Tags: shell, vim, command

In my Vim setup I'd like to add a configuration that runs a shell command with a certain mapping. Is there any possible way to do this in Vimscript?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`vim` has a a `system()` function:

```
:call system('date')
```

Comment: `vim.fn.system()` if you are using Neovim's API.

Answer (score 4):

I do this with traditional vi, so I assume it would work with vim as well.

In my .exrc I have:

```
map ^_ !}fmt 71 72^M
```

(That's a `^_` entered by typing **ctrl-V ctrl-_**, and a `^M` entered by typing **ctrl-V ctrl-M**

When I hit **ctrl-_** in vi, it reformats my current line to 72 characters.

Comment: There is `<C-_>` for `^_` and `<CR>` for `^M` (in vim, not in vi). Do not suggest using raw control codes in vimrc, this scraps the output of tools that expect text (like `cat vimrc | grep fmt`). It may also make VCS systems take vimrc as a binary file effectively disabling plain `vcs diff` and scrapping output of `vcs diff -a` just as it does for `grep`. There is also `nnoremap` in vim for this sort of thing (you need neither mode other then normal nor user mappings expansion here).

Comment: Good points.  Perhaps between my (vi-oriented) answer and your refinement, the OP will get a good answer.  :-)

Comment: What on earth does this have to do with the question?