# How to execute an external command in Vim script?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I want to execute an external command in Vim script but I don't how can I do this. For example I need to change a file permission using `chmod` command (Please assume application has enough permission to run the command)

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a shell command through vimscript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766033/how-to-run-a-shell-command-through-vimscript)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want users to see the output (or interact with the command) `:!` is the right command. For silent execution (as I suppose would be desired with your `chmod`), using `system()` is preferable. Especially on Windows, this avoids the popup of a command prompt that must be dismissed manually.

```
:call system('chmod +x ' . shellescape(fname))
```

Comment: Nice solution. Is there any way to get the output of call system() and show it manually to the user? For example via echo() command in Vim.

Comment: It returns the output, and the exit status is in `v:shell_error`. `:help system()` is your friend :-)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `:!` vim command. For example, to `echo 'Hello, World!'` from inside vim (and therefore from within a vim script, also), type

```
:! echo 'Hello, World\!'
```

in vim. Or, in a vim script, you can put just

```
! echo 'Hello, World\!'
```

The reason you need the \ before the ! is because vim performs special handling of ! characters in the argument of a ! command. If you were running a command that does not include any ! character, then you do not need to escape it.

If you want to read more in depth about this, you can type

```
:help :!
```

in vim, as @FDinoff said.

Comment: Also make sure to look at `:h :!`

Answer (score 2):

My preferred way is to push `Ctrl-z` or run `:sus` to suspend the vim process, then you can do whatever you want in the shell.

When you are done, run `fg` (foreground) to resume your vim session.

More info can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879219/how-to-temporarily-exit-vim-and-go-back).